# Vim abbreviation also applies to search (bug?)

Tags: vim

I think I just found a Vim bug, but before bothering Bram Moolenaar about it, I thought I'd check here if my understanding of Vim command syntax is right.

In my `.vimrc`, I have

```
cnoreabbrev W w
cnoreabbrev Q q
```

because I tend to hold shift depressed when typing `:w` or `:q`, giving `:W` or `:Q`. However, when I now try to search for `W` or `Q` with `/W`, `?Q`, etc., Vim finds occurrences of `w` or `q` instead. I find this surprising since I thought I had only abbreviated *commands*, not a search strings. Removing the two lines from my `.vimrc` gives the desired behavior.

Is this a bug or a feature of `cnoreabbrev`? It occurs both in the Debian-packaged Vim 7.3.923 and in the current Mercurial tip.

Comment: By the way, the [vim_use](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vim_use) mailing list is a good place to ask about potential bugs (that can turn out to be simple misunderstandings ;)).

Comment: @glts: sure, but so is SO :)

Comment: btw, I have `nnoremap <leader>w :w<cr>` mapping to do quick save, you may want to give it a try too. I don't think `:W` is easier to press, to press `:`, I usually use left shift, and `w` at left hand side too...

Comment: @Kent I normally use right shift (for colon). And sometimes I don't release it fast enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature.

If you hit space after `?Q` you will see is changed to `?q`

My way of fixing it is actually just to define a user command. (Since it starts with a capital anyways it works)

```
command! Q q
command! W w
```

Answer (score 3):

Command line abbreviations are notorious for causing subtle bugs that the user did not intend. The type of aliases that you are trying to create should probably be converted to  commands.

```
command W w
command Q q
```

I leave the completion, bang arguments, and range arguments as an exercise for the reader.

However if you really do want to use `cnoreabbrev` you need to do it carefully. I typically make an expression abbreviation that checks `getcmdtype()` and checks the value of the command line as well via `getcmdline()`. Example below

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> W getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() ==# 'W' ? 'w' : 'W'
```

If you don't want to create the logic yourself you can use a plugin by Hari Krishna Dara call [cmdalias](https://github.com/vim-scripts/cmdalias.vim).

For more help see:

```
:h Command-line-mode
:h :command
:h :map-expression
:h getcmdtype()
:h getcmdline()
```

Answer (score 2):

I won't say it is bug, it is a ..... feature.  :D

what you did is create an `ab`, only in command-line mode.

`/` (search) will bring you in command-line mode too. that's why the `ab` worked there as well.

```
:h vim-modes
```

you can see:

```
Command-line mode   In Command-line mode (also called Cmdline mode) you
Cmdline mode        can enter one line of text at the bottom of the
            window.  This is for the Ex commands, ":", the pattern
            search commands, "?" and "/", and the filter command,
            "!".
```

so

> This is for the Ex commands, ":", **the pattern
>                 search commands, "?" and "/",** and the filter command,
>                 "!".

Comment: At `:h getcmdtype()` you can see a few more Cmdline types, "debug", `input()`, and `:insert`/`:append` (I tried them).